# How can I use <s:property> to access a map using OGNL

Tags: struts2, ognl

I am trying to build a time tracking page where I display the project name, tasks and the hours billed for each day.

Here is the object I have on the Java side:

```
ProjectTO project1 = new ProjectTO();
project1.setProjectName("Project ABC");

TreeMap tasks = new TreeMap();
tasks.put("100_t1", "Requirement");
tasks.put("100_t2", "Development");         
project1.setTasks(tasks);       

TreeMap hours = new TreeMap();
hours.put("100_t1:Mon", "8");
hours.put("100_t1:Wed", "7");
project1.setHours(hours);
```

I'll need to look through this object to display values on the screen. Here is what I have on the JSP Page:

```
<s:iterator value="activeProjects">
<tbody>                     
    <tr>
        <td><p><s:property value="projectName"/></p></td>                           
    </tr>           

<s:iterator value="tasks">
    <tr>
        <td><s:property value="value"/></td>
        <td><s:property value="hours[%{key+':Mon'}]"/></td>
        <td><s:property value="hours[%{key+':Tue'}]"/></td>         
        ..........
    </tr>                           
</s:iterator>
</tbody>
</s:iterator>
```

The problem is figuring out how to display the hours. The code snippet shown above does not work. I can get it to work by using `<s:set var="mon" value="%{key+':Mon'}">` and referencing it in my td tags - hours[#mon]).

Is there a better solution?

Edit:

Thanks Dave. You are right. I am looking for `hours["100_t1:Mon"]`.

When I am iterating over the object in the view layer, the '100_t1' will need to be dynamically inserted based on the key of the task row i am iterating over. 'Mon', 'Tue' can be hardcoded.

I am going to see if I can do this better outside of the View layer as you recommended. As of now this is what I have working for me.

```
<s:iterator value="activeProjects">
<tbody>                     
    <tr>
        <td><p><s:property value="projectName"/></p></td>                           
    </tr>           

<s:iterator value="tasks">
             <s:set var="mon" value="%{key+':Mon'}"/> 
             <s:set var="tue" value="%{key+':Tue'}"/>
             <s:set var="wed" value="%{key+':Wed'}"/>
             <s:set var="thu" value="%{key+':Thu'}"/>
             <s:set var="fri" value="%{key+':Fri'}"/>
             <s:set var="sat" value="%{key+':Sat'}"/>
             <s:set var="sun" value="%{key+':Sun'}"/>
                    <tr>
                        <td><s:property value="value"/></td>
                        <td><s:property value="hours[#mon]"/></td>
                        <td><s:property value="hours[#tue]"/></td>
                        <td><s:property value="hours[#wed]"/></td>
                        <td><s:property value="hours[#thu]"/></td>
                        <td><s:property value="hours[#fri]"/></td>  
                        <td><s:property value="hours[#sat]"/></td>
                        <td><s:property value="hours[#sun]"/></td>                                          
                    </tr>                           
 </s:iterator>

</s:iterator>
```

Final Edit:

The following statement helps me avoid having to use s:set tags. I should have surrounded `hours[key + ':Mon']` within `%{}`.

```
value="%{hours[key + ':Mon']}"/>
```

also this works too

```
value="hours[key + ':Wed']"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're short-circuiting the OGNL evaluation you actually want.

The full OGNL expression you're looking for is actually `hours["100_t1:Mon"]`:

```
<s:property value="%{hours[key + ':Mon']}"/>
```

---

(IMO) you should be attach the hours to a task more concretely; as it is you're kind of subverting OOP paradigms by using maps and ad-hoc relationships.

Also, you know precisely how many days there are in a week, present the JSP with a list of daily hours. This avoids doing work in the view layer where testing is more difficult.

If you choose to not follow OOP/MVC norms, you can eliminate some redundancy like this:

```
<s:iterator value="{'Mon', 'Tue', ...etc...}" var="d">
  <s:set var="hrs" value="%{hours[key + ':' + #d]}"/>
  <td><s:property value="%{#hrs ? #hrs : 'N/A'}"/></td>
</s:iterator>
```

Again, I feel pretty strongly this is the wrong place to do this type of work.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I have edited my question to show what is working for me now. I dont feel quite good about the way i have implemented it..i think there is a better way to concretely attach hours to tasks. Curious - what do you mean by 'subverting OOP paradigms by using maps and ad-hoc relationships'

Comment: oh wait... your suggestion of <s:property value="%{hours[key + ':Mon']}"/> works!! I was not using the %{} in my code when i posted this question. Thanks!!!

Comment: @user1187958 A task is a class, not a map. A task's hours belong directly to a task. Ad-hoc string-based relationships aren't OOP. Java provides mechanisms (if verbosely) for directly relating data and operations; why not use them?